# Downloading a .tar file with httpClient and Angular

Tags: angular, httpclient, tar

I am trying to download a .tar file with HttpClient in Angular.
What I tried first was a normal request. The same procedure as i would with a normal text file but this didn't work. It returns a http failure response.

```
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public getData(){
    return this.http.get(`file.tar`);
  }
```

Next thing I tried was using the way of downloading an excel file, as the .tar contains csv files:

```
export class ApiService {


  downloadExcel() {
    const options = new RequestOptions({
              responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
              headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/vnd.ms-excel' })
          });
  
    this.httpClient.get('file.tar', options)
             .catch(errorResponse => Observable.throw(errorResponse.json()))
             .map((response) => { 
                   if (response instanceof Response) {
                      return response.blob();
                   }
                   return response;
              })
             .subscribe(data => saveAs(data, 'file.tar'),
                        error => console.log(error));
  
  }   
}
```

this returned even more http failure responses and i'm having problems with the imports aswell

for example

> Cannot find name 'RequestOptions'
>
> "Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable"
>
> Cannot find name 'saveAs'

my imports are:

```
mport { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, EMPTY, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

What would be the correct way to download a .tar file with angular and httpClient? Some explanation on what I did wrong would be great as well.

Comment: What kind of error first code sample returns?

Comment: Http failure response: 0 Unknown Error

Comment: Basically, your tar file is not `application/vnd.ms-excel`, it's more a `application/tar` mime type

Comment: This seems like a possible solution, but the import problem still remains.

Comment: `RequestOptions` is deprecated since V5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489115/requestoptions-deprecated-symbol-error-in-angular-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use file-saver package https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

```
export class ApiService {

downloadExcel() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: 'application/tar'
    });

    this.http
      .get('file.tar', { headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(errorResponse => Observable.throw(errorResponse.json())),
        map(response => {
          if (response instanceof Response) {
            return response.blob();
          }
          return response;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          const blob = new Blob(data, {
            type: 'application/tar;charset=utf-8'
          });
          FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'file.tar');
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }   
}
```

**Edit**
You have to use .pipe() method.

Comment: I updated my answer. You also should use .pipe() with the .get method.

Comment: What I learned from a comment above is that RequestOptions is deprecated since V5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489115/requestoptions-deprecated-symbol-error-in-angular-5   I guess this approach doesn't work in my case

Comment: I updated my answer correcting what was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property as **`catch`** in **`Observable`**. Instead you should use **`catchError`** from **`rxjs/operators`** inside **`pipe()`** method.
Use **`responseType: "blob"`** instead **`responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob`**.
You should use **`Content-Type`** header instead **`Accept`** header.

```
downloadExcel() {

    const options = { 
        responseType: "blob",  
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }) 
    };

    this.httpClient.get('file.tar', options).pipe(
            catchError(this.errorHandler('error in downloading file.'))
        ).subscribe((res: any) => {

            saveAs(res, 'file.tar');
    });
}

private errorHandler() {

    console.error(err)
}
```